# Can't use a domain username as a specified user in IIS 10.0

Tags: iis

i having a problem when i tried to use a domain user as a specified user name in basic settings-> connect as. I want to access a shared folder that located in another server.

The web server always says if the username or password isn't correct and always throw 500.19 error when I started to browse the application.

[Error Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuFrr.png)

However when I explore the app from IIS, it can be opened. I even tried a remote login to the server using the same username and password and it's just fine.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbPyV.png)

The server I am using for running the web server is a Workgroup computer and in a DMZ.  Is that a reason why IIS can't authecticate domain user?

Sorry for my terrible english here, because i'm in panic situation right now. I hope you can understand what i'm asking about and hope somebody has an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right, if your computer is not joined to the Active Directory domain, you won't be able to authenticate using a Domain account.

Should the site be publicly accessible? If so, you would want to set your authentication to Anonymous and then configure the authentication settings to authenticate either as a built in user (NETWORK SERVICE, AppPoolIdentity) or a local machine user created specifically for the application.

Comment: Hi Chris Budden, since this seems to be your first answer in Stack Overflow, I suggest you read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to improve your future answers.